# Toggle between two animations works only once

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

I'm trying to toggle between two animations in jQuery and it seems to be working only for the first time, but then it does some weird stuff when I try to toggle it again and I don't know why.
I used a switch in this case, but I also tried if statements and it does the same.

jQuery

```
    $("#one").animate({left:"250px", opacity:1}, 300)
    $("#two").animate({left:"150px", top:"150px", opacity:1}, 500)
    $("#three").animate({left:"10px", top:"250px", opacity:1}, 700)
    var toggle=1

    switch(toggle)
    {
        case 0:$("#main").click(function(){
            $("#one").animate({left:"250px", opacity:1}, 300)
            $("#two").animate({left:"150px", top:"150px", opacity:1}, 500)
            $("#three").animate({left:"10px", top:"250px", opacity:1}, 700)
            var toggle=1
        }); break;

        case 1:$("#main").click(function(){
            $("#one").animate({left:"0px", opacity:0}, 300)
            $("#two").animate({left:"0px", top:"0px", opacity:0}, 500)
            $("#three").animate({left:"0px", top:"0px", opacity:0}, 700)
            var toggle=0
        }); break; 
    }
    //end of switch
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HdFSv/1/

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var toggle=1
    $("#main").click(function(){
        if(toggle){
                $("#one").animate({left:"250px", opacity:1}, 300)
                $("#two").animate({left:"150px", top:"150px", opacity:1}, 500)
                $("#three").animate({left:"10px", top:"250px", opacity:1}, 700)
                toggle=0;
        }else{

                $("#one").animate({left:"0px", opacity:0}, 300)
                $("#two").animate({left:"0px", top:"0px", opacity:0}, 500)
                $("#three").animate({left:"0px", top:"0px", opacity:0}, 700)
                toggle=1;
        }
        //end of switch
    });
})
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v58Hx/)**

---

Or, with your original code (it was a bit buggy so it took me some time to debug it):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var toggle = 0;
    $("#main").click(function(){         
        switch(toggle){
            case 0:
                $("#one").animate({left:"250px", opacity:1}, 300)
                $("#two").animate({left:"150px", top:"150px", opacity:1}, 500)
                $("#three").animate({left:"10px", top:"250px", opacity:1}, 700)
                toggle=1;
         break;

            case 1:
                $("#one").animate({left:"0px", opacity:0}, 300)
                $("#two").animate({left:"0px", top:"0px", opacity:0}, 500)
                $("#three").animate({left:"0px", top:"0px", opacity:0}, 700)
                toggle=0;
        break; 
        }
        //end of switch 
    });
})
```

What I changed:

- you have to define toggle just once and outside the click function
- I removed the extra click handlers inside the switches

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rpVZG/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a global variable to control state, why are you creating a local variable inside the handler function and changing value of that ?

```
case 0:$("#main").click(function() {
        $("#one").animate({left:"250px", opacity:1}, 300)
        $("#two").animate({left:"150px", top:"150px", opacity:1}, 500)
        $("#three").animate({left:"10px", top:"250px", opacity:1}, 700)
        var toggle=1
    }); break;
```

instead of

```
var toggle=1
```

you should use

```
toggle=1
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea why `$('foo').attr('bar')` fails but working with data works...

http://jsfiddle.net/HdFSv/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#main").click(function () {
        if ($("#main").data('open')) {
            $("#main").data('open',0);
            $("#one").animate({left: "0px",opacity: 0}, 300);
            $("#two").animate({left: "0px",top: "0px",opacity: 0}, 500);
            $("#three").animate({left: "0px",top: "0px",opacity: 0}, 700);
        } else {
            $("#main").data('open',1);
            $("#one").animate({left: "250px",opacity: 1}, 300);
            $("#two").animate({left: "150px",top: "150px",opacity: 1}, 500);
            $("#three").animate({left: "10px",top: "250px",opacity: 1}, 700);
        }
    });
})
```